# Complex Comparisons

Tags: vba, excel

I'm kind of stumped here.  I am trying to look at unique numbers in ColA and get the text on the same row and compare that to the same (sometimes repeating) numbers in ColB and get the text on the same row.  If the text is different, I want to highlight in difference in the cell in ColC.

It's pretty hard to explain, so here is a picture.

[image]

I know the 1 in ColA = Required.  So, I want to look at all number 1s in ColB, and make sure the same row in ColC = Required.  In ColA, 2, 3, 4, & 5 are all required in ColC.  In ColB, the 3 & 4 should have a Required in ColC, but it says something different, so I want to color these cells orange.  Does it make sense?  I thought of using a Vlookup, but I'm not sure how it would work?

At this point in time, I have no code, but I'll post back if I come up with something that kind of works, or if I can get this working, I'll definitely post the solution.

I think the code will be something like this, but this doesn't follow the logic I described above.

```
Sub StillTrying()

Dim mCell As Range
Dim R As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Agent As Range
Dim AgentList As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set AgentList = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20")
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B20")

For Each Agent In AgentList
    For Each mCell In Rng
    Debug.Print mCell.Address
    Debug.Print Agent.Address

        If mCell.Value = Agent.Value And mCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Agent.Offset(0, 2).Value Then
        ' do nothing
        Else
            mCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 1).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 39423
            End With
            R = R + 1
        End If
    Next mCell
Next Agent

End Sub
```

Basically, C& and C8 should be orange.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve this using conditional formatting.

In cell `C2`, apply the following conditional formatting rule:

[image]

Then copy that cell's format to each of the other cells in column C.

---

If your firewall is blocking images on `i.stack.imgur.com`, the image shows the `Edit Formatting Rule` dialogue, with the selection set to `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, and the formula being `=NOT(C2=VLOOKUP(B2,A:C,3,FALSE))`, and the format showing an orange fill.

Comment: *Then copy that cell's format* - or, just set the conditional format's *applies to* range to the cells you want it to apply to. The columns should probably be absolute (`$`) in the formula though, especially if you change your mind and want to highlight the entire row instead of just a cell in column C.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I did think of setting the range in the conditional formatting dialogue - but that would have required another screenshot, and I'm lazy!  :D  (And I did, briefly, think about absolute references - but I wasn't sure which ones would be absolute and which would be relative, and the `3` would have to be changed if column C was moved to column X for instance - so that began to become all too difficult to describe.)

Comment: I can't see the image.  I'm pretty sure it's blocked by my firm's firewall.  Can you edit your post and do a Ctrl+K over that so I can see it?  Thanks.

Comment: @r_michael - It's not code, so Ctrl-K won't help.  I added a word description of what the dialogue should look like.  Hopefully you will be able to follow it.

Comment: Ahhh!  Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format!!  Brilliant!!  Thanks so much!!